# html within border

Tags: html

I have the following:

```
    <a href="http://www.youtube.com/"  title="Tonight">
    <img src="images/video.jpg" alt="Tonight Icon" />Hotel </a>
```

This shows and image that is clickable along with text underneath - Hotel, which is also clickable.

How do I put a border around the jpg and the text (Hotel) so that is is all within a border.

I tried:

```
    <div border="1px">
    <a href="http://www.youtube.com/"  title="Tonight">
    <img src="images/video.jpg" alt="Tonight Icon" border="1" />Hotel </a></div>
```

but that did not put a border around the jpeg and text.

Comment: Use styles, not `border="1"`. `div`s are not tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can style at the element level (inline) using CSS:

```
<div style="border: 1px solid #000000;">
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/"  title="Tonight">
<img src="images/video.jpg" alt="Tonight Icon" />Hotel </a></div>
```

This uses shorthand notation of border properties, which you can read on [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp).

**Update**

There is a *natural flow* with regards to the visual formatting model [detailed by the W3](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html) (*outdated, but principle remains*) which states that inline elements should be contained inside a block element, thus the formatting (border in this case) should occur at the block level. The link/image/text in this example should be in a `<p>` element, thus the styling should take place at the `<div>` level. You can surely include the `<img>` within a `<p>`, but then the styling will occur at the block element.

Comment: the div element is not necessary. Might as well add it to the <a>.

Comment: @ComputerArts How else would you like to surround both the image and text? The OP requested to "put a border around the jpg and the text (Hotel) so that is is all within a border."

Comment: The <img> is within the <a> so a border on <a> will also include the image

Comment: However, *Hotel* should be within a `<p>` block. You should style at the block element when possible, not at the inline element.

Comment: @ComputerArts I'm not arguing that it won't work. I'm telling you it is poor practice

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-alt-techniques/ Example 6.3. You're right about the fact that Hotel should be in a <p> block. But still unsure about having to wrap the elements in a div to add a border!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16927/discussion-between-computerarts-and-njk)

Answer (score 0):

add a style to your link.

```
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/"  title="Tonight" style="border:1px solid #000000; display:inline-block;">
    <img src="images/video.jpg" alt="Tonight Icon" border="1" />
    Hotel 
</a>
```

Edit: added display:inline-block for cross-browser compatibility.

Comment: OP is requesting a "border around the jpg and the text (Hotel)"

Comment: Exactly. This will add a border around both. What's the difference between adding the border to the wrapping <a> than to add an extra <div> around it all ???

Comment: Also avoids switching to a block element

Comment: Because *Hotel* should be inside a `<p>` block.

Comment: You don't need to wrap Hotel in a <p> block. Personnaly, I'm not a fan of putting a paragraph inside an anchor. It just feels dirty and unnecessary! :P

Comment: @ComputerArts I never said to put a block element inside an inline element. There should be a block element around the inline elements.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the proper way to do this using CSS:

In your stylesheet, create a class:

```
<style>
    .withBorder {
        board:1px solid #000000;
    }
</style>
```

Use that class in your wrapping DIV:

```
<div class="withBorder">
    <a href="http://www.youtube.com/"  title="Tonight">
    <img src="images/video.jpg" alt="Tonight Icon" border="1" />Hotel </a>
</div>
```

It's a good practice to separate your HTML from your styling. Using an inline style tag will work, but if you have another box and style it, then decide later that you want to change the look, you can edit the CSS class instead of having to edit each HTML inline style individually.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="border:2px">
    <a href="http://www.youtube.com/"  title="Tonight">
    <img src="images/video.jpg" alt="Tonight Icon" border="1" />Hotel </a>
</div>
```